# changing placeholder text in parse loginviewcontroller

Tags: parse-platform, nsattributedstring

So I'd like to change the username placeholder in the Parse LoginView controller, but the text is showing up as fuzzy - how do either set the right shadows/highlights ... or just change the text without changing the style attributes.

https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

Both of these below create the fuzzy gray text without the right shadow/highlights

```
logInViewController.logInView.usernameField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Phone" attributes:@{}];

logInViewController.logInView.usernameField.placeholder = @"phone";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which effect you want to apply (there are a few example/screenshot on your link).
But here what you could do or set up as you want (and apply the value you want):

```
NSAttributedString *originalUserNamePlaceHolder = logInViewController.logInView.usernameField.attributedPlaceholder;

NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[shadow setShadowBlurRadius:2.0];
[shadow setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[shadow setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 2.0)];
    
NSDictionary *attributesCustom = @{NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:theUIColorYouWant};
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"customText" attributes: attributesCustom];
logInViewController.logInView.usernameField.attributedPlaceholder = attrString;
```

Note that `customText` could be `[originalUserNamePlaceHolder string];`

You can read more about the various effect you wan apply [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW16).

Now, you could do this to retrieve the setting you want to mimic (because you like it), retrieving its specific settings:

```
__block NSDictionary *attributesRetrieved;
[attrString enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]) options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSLog(@"Attrs: %@", attrs);
    attributesRetrieved = [attrs copy];
}];
```

There should be only one attribute (for the whole text).
For example, on the one I set:
You got:

> attributesRetrieved: {
> NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1";
> NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, 2} blur = 2 color = {UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.5 1}";
>
> }
> So you can retrieve the previous setting I put before.